# When to commit db.session using Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a web app that uses Flask Sqlalchemy to modify database entries.
The app has a multitude of different 'routes' which do different things.
Within a given route, the code might edit a number of different objects (mapped to database tables), and some routes iterate over tens of objects, editing each one as it goes.

Currently, I'm running `db.session.commit()` after editing each object, but I suspect that might be excessive, and likely slowing things down.

When iterating over a list/dict, should I need to commit the session within each iteration? or should I be able to simply commit once after the iterations are complete?

Comment: you can do both, but depend on your fail condition and its recovery how you will handle it all. if all dependent on each other than commiting together is good to go